# Set table view footer while loading need cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, tablefooterview

I'm trying to add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to the `footerView` of my `UITableView`.

I'm using `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` to detect when the user scrolls to the bottom, and I fetch new data, then reload the tableview.

I've tried two approach, and none fits what I want :

1. Adding the activity indicator in the `viewDidLoad` method works fine, when I scroll down the indicator shows perfectly. But, when I only have like one or two rows : the indicator shows up (logic, but not what I want...).
2. Adding the activity indicator in the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` methods, when I detect that I need to fetch new data (and remove it when I got the data). The problem is that the footer is displayed after the scroll is finished, meaning that the user doesn't see it (except if he scrolls again).

Any thoughts on a better solution ?

Comment: 2nd approach is ok..but after you fetch new data just change the contentOffset of tableView manually to show the data below.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it worked perfectly. I'll mark as answer if you want to post it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2nd approach is ok..but after you fetch new data just change the `contentOffset` of `tableView` manually to show the data below.

Answer (score 2):

I do faced the same issue and finally figured out a solution,

I started animating the activity indicator in ViewDidLoad and made it Hidden,

```
 [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
 self.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
```

and in

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

while fetching datas make

```
self.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
```

and when fetching is done make

```
self.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
```

Hope this one helps